# How Can I Make a Form That Will Update My Table and Display as a Row on My TeamStats Page?

Tags: php, css, mysql, html

I was wanting to make a form that will allow me to update my tables in my database and will then display on my pre-made table on my webpage.  I was wanting to at least able to insert data, but being able to also say delete a row with the form would be great too.

I have my tables in phpadmin.  I wanted this form to be able to update what I have in phpadmin and then display as a new table row in my table on my webpage. Below is an example table I have and I had called some values already from my database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>      
<center>
<div>
<div class="container">
<table class="responsive-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Team Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Match Result</th>
    <th scope="col">Date Played</th>
    <th scope="col">Location</th>

  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">User: <?=$_SESSION['name']?></td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row"><?=$Team_Name?></td>
    <td><?=$Match_Result?></td>
   <td><?=$Date_Played?></td>
    <td><?=$Location?></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody> 
 </table>
 </div>
<script 
src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'> 
</script>
</div>
<footer id="footer"> 
&copy; 2019
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to insert new information into my Game_List table and then add another row on my webpage.

Comment: Way to broad to answer here also you should search this on Google for basic [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+MySQL+insert+%2F+update+%2F+delete+tutorials) keep in mind most of them are really basic and handle security really bad so you will have to know how to protect against SQL injections and Cross site scripting also.. Or simply use old deprecated functions like `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqli functions of PHP, store the result and display it in the table via the short php tag using all the variables where you've stored it.

EDIT:
A very brief example of how I do it is

````php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $UCPdatabase = "sarp_game";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
    }
    else
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $UCPdatabase);

$sql = "SELECT `Model`, `ID`, `Name`, `Level`, `Money`, `authyID` FROM `players` WHERE `Name` = '".$_SESSION['username']."' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(!$result){
            echo "Error: ", mysqli_error($conn);
            die("|ABORT|");
        }

        if($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $skin = "<img src=\"".dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])))."\images\skins\\".$rows['Model'].".png\" height=\"300px\" width=\"400px\">";
            $skin = str_replace('\\', '/', $skin);
            echo $skin."<br>";
            echo "<div id=\"content\">ID: {$rows['ID']} | Name: {$rows['Name']} | Level: {$rows['Level']} | Money: $ {$rows['Money']}</div>";
            echo "<br>";
    ```
````